# Nginx certificate authentication of a specific location

Tags: apache, nginx

Using Apache I created an HTTPS site that contains a folder called **secure** *[which I want to access with user and password]* and another folder called **verysecure** *[which I want to access with certificate authentication]*.

When I access the site using *https://www.example.com* I get the default index.html file located in the root, as would be expected. When I access *https://www.example.com/secure/* I provide the user and password and get the index.html file located in that folder. When I access *https://www.example.com/verysecure/* the certificate popup window allows me to choose the certificate that I want to use and upon doing so I get the index.html file located in that folder.

How can I configure Nginx so that the certificate chooser pop up window comes only when I access *https://www.example.com/verysecure/* and not when I access *https://www.example.com/* or *https://www.example.com/secure/* ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to [this](https://forum.nginx.org/read.php?29,173747) thread from official nginx development forum, you can't (although this thread is almost 10 years old, SSL/TLS re-handshake still doesn't supported by nginx). The only workaround suggested by Igor Sysoev is to use an optional client certificate verification

```
ssl_verify_client optional;
```

and then checking the [`$ssl_client_verify`](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_ssl_module.html#var_ssl_client_verify) variable value:

```
location /verysecure/
    if ($ssl_client_verify != SUCCESS) {
        # deny client
        return 403;
        # or process the request on some internal location, see
        # http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#internal
        # rewrite ^ /internal last;
    }
    ...
}
```

However using this workaround the certificate chooser window will popup (**only** for clients who had the correct certificate installed) on the initial TLS handshaking, not only on visiting the `/verysecure/` URI.

Comment: Thanks @Ivan but that's exactly what I am doing right now. However I was asked to provide the exact same functionality that I can achieve with Apache using nginx. I will keep looking and either post the answer - if I find it - or accept your answer.

Comment: Some SSL customization can be made with the `lua-nginx-module` (check [this](https://github.com/openresty/lua-nginx-module#ssl_certificate_by_lua_block) documentaion section and below), however I doubt that behavior can be achieved even with that one.